# How to handle multiple, dynamically created listeners to a single ChildProcess in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a child process worker, that receives some data and sends back results to dynamically attached listener.

Simplified code:

```
//app.js
var worker = childProcess.fork('./app_modules/workers/worker1.js');
worker.setMaxListeners(0);
require('./app_modules/sockets-user/foobar.js')(io, worker);

//foobar.js
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('trigger', function (data) {
    worker.send(data);
    worker.once('message', function(responseData) {

      //here I get a response from worker
      socket.emit('response', responseData);

    });
  });
});
```

It was working great until I discovered that If socket.on('trigger' is triggered at the very exact moment by different users every listener would receive the same message.

I could change worker.once to worker.on but its not a fix, because I would have to filter incoming data and then probably find a way to clear dynamically added listeners. What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably one of the easiest solutions would be to pass some user-specific data (e.g. remote IP address and port or some other unique identifier) to the worker than merely gets passed right back to the parent in the response. This way you can match up the response with the correct socket.

This means that you would only have one `message` listener (added outside of the socket.io `connection` handler). You would then look up the socket based on the information passed in the response, and send whatever data back to that client. For example:

```
//foobar.js
worker.on('message', function(responseData) {
  // assuming worker returns `{id: ..., data: ...}`
  var socket = io.sockets.sockets[responseData.id];
  if (socket)
    socket.emit('response', responseData.data);
});
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('trigger', function (data) {
    worker.send({ id: socket.id, data: data });
  });
});
```

Comment: This is true. I even did it just to find out If I can but it introduces another issue. I need a way to remove the dynamically created listeners, I cannot let them simply add up.

Comment: Which listeners are you referring to?

Comment: If I have the code like this, every new worker.on('message' adds another listener to the worker object, so every new user adds new listener and inherits listeners created in the past. If I use worker.once it causes the issue described in the question

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify what I had in mind.

Comment: Yes my friend, this is the only solution that I had in my mind. I guess it is the only one that makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: You could dynamically remove event handler(s) on socket disconnect, but inside the worker `message` handler, you'd still have to look up the appropriate socket by some identifier since the worker is being used by more than one client simultaneously. So putting the `message` handler in the "root" scope just makes things simpler.